# How to get the current changed state of a fragment inside an Activity?

Tags: java, android

I've made 2 Activities. The first Activity contains a button, which intents to second Activity. In the second Activity I have two buttons and a container. Each button adds and replaces a fragment into the container. Each fragment in the container contains button, which intents back to first activity.

My question is: I press button2 in my second activity, that reveals fragment2 in the container, and I press fragment2, it takes me to the first activity. When I press the button of the first activity, it intents to second activity, and the container is empty again. I want to see in the container the already pressed fragment2 (i gave a background color to be visible). How can I do that?

First activity java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageButton bbbb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bbbb = findViewById(R.id.bbbb);
        bbbb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }});}}
```

Second activity java:

```
public class Main2Activity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ImageButton snipe;
    private ImageButton aim;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        snipe = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.snipe);
        aim = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aim);
        final View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.snipe:
                        FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
                        BlankFragment F1 = new BlankFragment();
                        FT.add(R.id.fragment_container1, F1);
                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container1, F1);
                        FT.commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.aim:

                        FragmentManager FM1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT1 = FM1.beginTransaction();
                        BlankFragment2 F11 = new BlankFragment2();
                        FT1.add(R.id.fragment_container1, F11);
                        FT1.replace(R.id.fragment_container1, F11);
                        FT1.commit();
                        break; }}};
        findViewById(R.id.snipe).setOnClickListener(mListener);
        findViewById(R.id.aim).setOnClickListener(mListener); }}
```

One of the fragments java (both have the same code):

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment{

ImageButton b1;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        b1 = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent); }});
        return rootView; }}
```

Comment: If you go to Activity1 from Activity2 and then go back to Activity1, Activity2 and all of it's fragments are removed. So going back to Activity2 is like starting fresh. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Is there any way to keep Activity 2 so as it was? I'm thinking like saving the current state as it was. Like getCurrentitem, when I do not use fragments, or maybe Saveinstantstate, or Sharedpreferences, or something like that. I would really appreciate a code, where this mechanism functions: that when I press button in Activity 1, the current fragment I used before, with it's contents in container appear in Activity 2.
If you have any ideas, they are most welcome :)